# How to implement dynamic Channel where producer is 3rd party?

Tags: c#, channel, producer-consumer, system.threading.channels

I receive continuous data into `NewMessage(Msg)` that I need to offload to a threadpool/worker thread and latency is very important. `NewMessage(Msg)` is an inherited method from a 3rd party library where I can't or rather don't want to make changes to it's parameters.

The `Msg`'s received within `NewMessage(Msg)` frequency is variable and can be a 300 `Msg`' per second or even just 1.  Also the messages are continuous from the time that I start the application until I end it.

I have read up on Channel and can implement it in a basic format but I need a more complicated version that I can't find examples of.

Basic implementation thus far:

```
private readonly Channel<Msg> channel;
private readonly ChannelWriter<Msg> writer;
private readonly ChannelReader<Msg> reader;
private CancellationTokenSource ctSource;
private CancellationToken ct;

void CTor()
{
    channel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<Msg>();
    writer = channel.Writer;
    reader = channel.Reader;
    ctSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
}
void NewMessage(Msg newMsg)
{
    if(!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {       
        channel.TryWrite(newMsg);
    }
}
async void ConsumeMessages(CancellationToken ct)
{
    await foreach(Msg newMsg in channel.Reader.ReadAsync())
    {
        if(ct.IsCancellationRequested) { return; }
        MethodConsume(newMsg);
    }
}
void StartConsuming()
{
    ct = new ctSource.Token;
    ConsumeMessages(ct);
}
void StopConsuming()
{
    if(ct.Exists)            // looking for correct syntax
    { ctSource.Cancel; }
}
```

How can I implement multiple consumers to ensure `Msg` consumption is optimal in terms of latency?

Comment: The question is unclear and you *certainly* don't need all that code. You don't even need a `Channel` field. Just create a method that creates the channel internally and returns a `ChannelReader`. The consuming method only needs a ChannelReader parameter. To stop, call `ChannelWriter.TryComplete` in the producer method. No `Start` call is needed

Comment: BTW `async void` is a bug. Such methods can't be awaited and can are only meant for asynchronous event handlers

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I tried to clarify my question in the edit.

Comment: Add the actual FIX code and specify the library you use. All FIX libraries have quirks, some more than others.

Comment: If you want multiple consumers, you can just call the `StartConsuming` multiple times, and see what positive effect does this have to latency. Why can't say to you how many consumers is optimal, because it depends on the specifics of the workload.

Answer (score 1):

May not the exact solution but I would suggest implementing a robust and efficient solution using the System.Threading.Channels namespace in .NET, ensuring thread safety, FIFO processing, dynamic scaling of consumers, and monitoring of consumer efficiency.

You can create Producter

```cs
using System.Threading.Channels;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

public class MessageProcessor
{
    private readonly Channel<Msg> channel;
    private readonly ChannelWriter<Msg> writer;
    private Task _workerTask;
    private CancellationTokenSource ctSource;

    public MessageProcessor()
    {
        channel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<Msg>();
        writer = channel.Writer;
        ctSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }

    public void NewMessage(Msg newMsg)
    {
        if (!ctSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            writer.TryWrite(newMsg);
        }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _workerTask = StartProcessingAsync();
    }

    private async Task StartProcessingAsync()
    {
        var reader = channel.Reader;
        await Parallel.ForEachAsync(reader.ReadAllAsync(ctSource.Token), ctSource.Token, async (msg, token) =>
        {
            await ProcessMessageAsync(msg, token);
        });
    }

    private async Task ProcessMessageAsync(Msg msg, CancellationToken token)
    {
        Console.Writeln(msg)
    }

    public async Task StopAsync()
    {
        writer.Complete();
        await _workerTask;
        ctSource.Cancel();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
public class Msg
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

    public Msg(string content)
    {
        Content = content;
        Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var messageProcessor = new MessageProcessor();
        messageProcessor.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            var messageContent = $"Message {i}";
            messageProcessor.NewMessage(new Msg(messageContent));
            await Task.Delay(10);
        }
        messageProcessor.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need for this `MessageProcessor` class at all. In fact, this makes using them harder than it needs to be. Channels are equivalent to Go channels, not F# agents

Comment: ok. It's just an alternative way and maybe a more structured way to code... maybe I am wrong... most probably i'm wrong and over thinking...

Comment: You can improve simplify this code quite a bit, by using `Parallel.ForEachAsync` and making the methods asynchronous. To complete you *need* to use `ChannelWriter.Complete` otherwise `NewMessage` will keep working. Once you use `Complete` the reader will eventually terminate. You can save the task created by `ForEachAsync` to a field, eg `_workerTask=Parallel.ForEachAsync(reader.ReadAllAsync()(msg,token)=>{ ...});` and await that in `StopAsync`, eg `Task StopAsync() { _writer.TryComplete(); await _workerTask;}`

Comment: @Phoenix404, some points  within AdjustConsumersBasedOnLoad(), I get error at consuers.Values...  ->  List<Task> does not contain a definition for 'Values'.   Also in ShouldReduceConsumer(), operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type task and bool.  And also there, currentConsumerCount does not exist in the current context.  I am using net core 8

Comment: @Phoenix404, also in ReduceConsumers, Task does not contain a definition for 'Value'

Comment: @Phoenix404, thanks. As I mention to PanagiotisKavanos, your solution also work but when the consume load takes about twice as long as the producer to add messages, the consumption of subsequent messages increases drastically, non-linearly.  Your first post included load management -  you removed that?   any comments or ideas on that?

Comment: @Phoenix404 , when the cosumption thread takes about twice as long to consume a message, as the producer thread takes to add a message (3 vs 6ms)...     Your code however did perform better than his.

Answer (score 0):

**Processing FIX messages in a pipeline**

From more comments it looks like the real scenario is processing FIX messages. In the FIX protocol the source (eg a stock exchange) sends messages like stock orders in a continuous stream. The clients *must* process the messages or lose them. FIX libraries invariably have quirks so the specifics matter. All of them work in a somewhat reactive manner though, pushing incoming messages to applications.

Let's start with QuickFix's [example](https://new.quickfixn.org/n/documentation/#item-example-message-cracker-2) for processing incoming orders. The library is really old (11 years), based on old Java (so it has no properties, delegates or generics) and instead of callback methods, it expects clients to implement specific methods.  Despite the name, `FromApp` is the *callback* that receives application messages like new orders. The `MessageCracker.Crack` method in turn calls the strongly-typed `OnMessage` callback based on the message's type  :

```
public class MyApplication : MessageCracker, IApplication
{
    public void OnMessage(
        QuickFix.FIX42.NewOrderSingle ord,
        SessionID sessionID)
    {
        ProcessOrder(ord.Price, ord.OrderQty, ord.Account);
    }

    protected void ProcessOrder(
        Price price,
        OrderQty quantity,
        Account account)
    {
        //...
    }

    public void FromApp(Message msg, SessionID sessionID)
    {
        Crack(msg, sessionID);
    }
...
}
```

The orders could be processed on a different thread by using an `ActionBlock<NewOrderSingle>` :

```
public class MyApplication : MessageCracker, IApplication
{
    ActionBlock<NewOrderSingle> _block;

    public MyApplication()
    {
        _block=new ActionBlock<NewOrderSingle>(ord=>ProcessOrder(ord.Price, ord.OrderQty, ord.Account));
    }

    public void OnMessage(
        QuickFix.FIX42.NewOrderSingle ord,
        SessionID sessionID)
    {
        _block.Post(ord);
    }
```

This guarantees that all orders will be processed in a different thread, in order.

We could use a different block per symbol :

```
public class MyApplication : MessageCracker, IApplication
{
    ConcurrentDictionary<string,ActionBlock<NewOrderSingle>> _blocks;

    public MyApplication()
    {
        _blocks=new ConcurrentDictionary<string,ActionBlock<NewOrderSingle>>();
    }

    public void OnMessage(
        QuickFix.FIX42.NewOrderSingle ord,
        SessionID sessionID)
    {
        var symbol=ord.Symbol.getValue(); // Java origins, no properties        
        var block=_blocks.GetOrAdd(symbol,smb=>new ActionBlock<NewOrderSingle>(ord=>ProcessOrder(ord.Price, ord.OrderQty, ord.Account));

        _block.Post(ord);
    }
```

---

**Second Answer**

From the comments :

> I am not in control of the producer - that is an interface I inherit and I must work with NewMessage(Msg) within my class.

In that case it's probably easier to use [ActionBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1?view=net-8.0), which encapsulates buffering, parallelism and ordered processing. Items posted to an `ActionBlock` are processed by a single background worker by default but the number can change.

Assuming the interface only has a `NewMessage(Msg)` method and the class is disposable, the block can be created in the constructor and stopped in `Dispose` or `DisposeAsync`. `NewMessage` only has to post the message to the block :

```
class MyConsumerClass:IExternalConsumer,IAsyncDisposable
{
    ActionBlock<Msg> _block;
    ILogger<MyConsumerClass> _logger;
    
    public MyConsumerClass(ILogger<MyConsumerClass> logger )
    {
        _block=new ActionBlock<Msg>(ProcessMessage);
        _logger=logger;
    }

    void NewMessage(Msg msg)
    {
        _block.Post(msg);
    }

    async Task ProcessMessage(Msg msg)
    {
        try
        {
            // Process the message
        }
        //Uncaught exceptions will terminate the block
        catch(Exception exc)
        {       
            _logger.LogException(exc,"...");
        }

    }

...
}
```

The `DisposeAsync` method stops the block and waits for pending messages to complete. This snippet omits the full disposal pattern and just shows the minimum code :

```
    async Task StopBlockAsync()
    {
        _block.Complete();
        await _block.Completion;
    }
    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        //Standard IAsyncDisposable implementation ommited
        await StopBlockAsync();
    }
```

---

**Original Answer**

Using channels is far easier than this. There's no need for fields and `CancellationToken` is only needed if we want to stop producing, consuming *and* discard all pending messages.

All a producer needs to do is return a `ChannelReader`, nothing more :

```
ChannelReader<Msg> Produce(CancellationToken token=default)
{
    var channel=Channel.CreateUnbounded<Msg>();
    var writer=channel.Writer;

    //Emulate an actual producer
    _ = Task.Run(async ()=>{
        while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
            //Sending may be blocked if we use a Bounded channel that's full
            await writer.SendAsync( new Msg(....),token);

        }
    },token)
    //Ensure we `Complete` even in case of error, propagating the error
    .ContinueWith(t=>{
        writer.TryComplete(t.Exception);
    });
    return channel.Reader;
}
```

Keeping the `Channel` inside `Produce` means the method has full control of its lifetime, completion and possibly error handling. This simplifies consuming or composing multiple steps a *lot* easier.

The consumer doesn't need access to the Channel itself, only the reader.

```
async Task Consume(ChannelReader<Msg> reader, CancellationToken token=default)
{
    await foreach(var msg in reader.ReadAllAsync(token))
    {
        //Extra check if we want to exit rearly
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested) return;

        //Process the message
        ....
    }
}
```

This allows for easy composition:

```
var reader=Produce();
await Consume(reader);
```

Once `Produce` ends, completion will be propagated to `Consume`. We can terminate prematurely if we pass an optional CancellationToken :

```
//Cancel after 1 minute
var cts=new CancellationTokenSource(60000);
var reader=Produce(cts.CancellationToken);
await Consume(reader,cts.CancellationToken);
```

**Create a Pipeline**

The processing method could return its own `ChannelReader` with the results of processing. This would allow creating a pipeline of processing steps/blocks

```
ChannelReader<Msg2> Convert2(ChannelReader<Msg> reader, CancellationToken token=default)
{
    var channel=Channel.CreateUnbounded<Msg2>();
    var writer=channel.Writer;

    _ = Task.Run(async ()=>{
        await foreach(var msg in reader.ReadAllAsync(token))
        {
            var msg= SomehowProduceMsg2(msg);
            await writer.SendAsync( msg2,token);
        }
    },token)
    //Ensure we `Complete` even in case of error, propagating the error
    .ContinueWith(t=>{
        writer.TryComplete(t.Exception);
    });
    return channel.Reader;
}
```

This way we can create a pipeline of processing steps:

```
var reader=Produce();
var reader2=await Convert2(reader);
await Consume2(reader2);
```

**Reducing boilerplate**

The code starts getting too verbose but luckily, it's easy to make a generic `Convert` method that calls a `Func<T1,T2>` we pass as a parameter :

```
ChannelReader<T2> Convert<T1>(ChannelReader<T1> reader, Func<T1,T2> func, MsgCancellationToken token=default)
{
    var channel=Channel.CreateUnbounded<T2>();
    var writer=channel.Writer;

    _ = Task.Run(async ()=>{
        await foreach(var msg in reader.ReadAllAsync(token))
        {
            var msg= func(msg);
            await writer.SendAsync( msg2,token);
        }
    },token)
    //Ensure we `Complete` even in case of error, propagating the error
    .ContinueWith(t=>{
        writer.TryComplete(t.Exception);
    });
    return channel.Reader;
}

...

var reader2=Convert(reader1,SomehowProduceMsg2,token);
```

**Parallel Processing**

An easy way to process more than 1 message at a time is to use `Parallel.ForEachAsync` instead of `await foreach`, with the degree-of-parallelism we want:

```
ChannelReader<Msg2> Convert2(ChannelReader<Msg> reader, int dop=1,CancellationToken token=default)
{
    var channel=Channel.CreateUnbounded<Msg2>();
    var writer=channel.Writer;

    _ = Task.Run(async ()=>{

        await Parallel.ForEachAsync(reader.ReadAllAsync(token),(msg,t)=>{
            var msg= SomehowProduceMsg2(msg);
            await writer.SendAsync( msg2,t);
        },
        new ParallelOptions{ MaxDegreeOfParallelism = dop},
        token);
    },token)
    //Ensure we `Complete` even in case of error, propagating the error
    .ContinueWith(t=>{
        writer.TryComplete(t.Exception);
    });
    return channel.Reader;
}
```

Or, using the generic method :

```
async Task MyConvertFunc(ChannelReader<Msg1> reader,CancellationToken token=default)
{
    await Parallel.ForEachAsync(reader.ReadAllAsync(token),(msg,t)=>{
            var msg= SomehowProduceMsg2(msg);
            await writer.SendAsync( msg2,t);
    },
    new ParallelOptions{ MaxDegreeOfParallelism = dop},
    token);
}

var reader2=Convert(reader1,MyConvertFunc,token);
```

Comment: ok thanks @PanagiotisKanavos but, what can I do in lieu of //Emulate an actual producer, block of code, if my producer is the third party library that pushes `Msg`s  into `NewMessage(Msg)`.   Which is an inherited method in my class/app.  Hope I am making sense

Comment: What do you mean? What do you get from that library? An IEnumerable<T> ? Something else? You could create a function that adds everything from an `IEnumerable` to a channel and returns the reader

Comment: I receive only `Msg`  in `NewMessage(Msg)`.  Also please advise on why you  use `ReadAllAsync` vs `ReadAsync`. Does that pull all the current queued `Msg` vs pulling one by one?

Comment: `ReadAllAsync` returns an `IAsyncEnumerable` that can be used with `await foreach`. This way you don't have to loop manually. You can also use `System.Linq.Async`'s method like `Where`, `Select` etc to reduce the code even further.

Comment: did you understand my point that I am not in control of the producer - that is an interface I inherit and I must work with `NewMessage(Msg)` within my class.

The only touching point with the producer is the `NewMessaage(Msg)`,  where data flow is received.

Comment: I can only start and stop the flow of the producer's data stream, which is continuous.

Comment: You didn't post that interface, so I can't guess what methods are provided or how they're called. Are you saying that `NewMessage` is a callback? In that case all you need is access to a `ChannelWriter` to post messages. If the class's lifetime matches the data and the class implements `IAsyncDisposable`, the only additional thing you need is to call `.TryComplete` and await completion in `DisposeAsync`

Comment: On the other hand, perhaps you should look at [ActionBlock<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1?view=net-8.0)? That's a higher level abstraction that already encapsulates buffering, linking, cancellation, parallelism etc.

Comment: @Allstar I added an example that shows how to use ActionBlock instead of Channels assuming only `NewMessage` exists and stopping on disposal

Comment: thank you. Got it to work in a simple console app and monitor the cosumers worktime per message. When the Consumer consume time per message is say, double of the producer. The consume time per message starts increasing drastically, non-linear.  And that was just on 100 messages.   Any comment or idea on how to  prevent such backlog on high-flow of messages?

Comment: @Allstar it's neither the channel's nor the ActionBlock's fault. What does the processing step do? Can this processing be broken into independent steps? Both Channels and especially Dataflow were built to create a *pipeline* of blocks, each running on its own thread/task. This is similar to how shell scripts work, with each tool in the script passing data to the next one.

Comment: @Allstar a typical example is to post URLs to CSV files to a TransformBlock that downloads them and passes the path to a TransformBlock that parses the CSV into rows, then on to a BatchBlock that batches rows in eg arrays of 1K-5K records, then on to an ActionBlock that imports them into SQL Server with SqlBulkInsert. This way you don't have to wait for downloads to parse and import files.

Comment: hi @PanagtiotisKanavos,  in "production" (and not my testing console app) the reader from the block gets pulls about two variables from the `Msg` , does if() checks and then it goes to a longer running CPU bound synchronous method that I want to pass off to an independent thread with Task.Run, or await Task.Run.   The work that the reader does before it hands off to CPU bound is as minimal as possible without having to consume unwanted information.   The OnNewMessage() is incoming FIX messages.  I see you have spoken about trading apps in other SO questions.

Comment: @PanagiotisKavanos,  sorry if I was a better programmer I would be able to you use your answer and code better - I  am not experienced or good enough with concurrency / coding

Comment: @Allstar you should have started with that and posted real code. FIX libraries in .NET have their own quirks and I've worked with FIX in the past. No matter the quirks, all use some form of asynchronous processing both because nobody would use them otherwise *and* because they would risk losing messages. That means you can post the incoming message to either a Channel or Dataflow block and process it on another thread. If you use QuickFix, `FromApp` could post each message to a `TransformBlock<Message,...>` for processing. If you use a MessageCracker, `OnMessage` would post orders to a block

Comment: @PanagiotisKavanos,  yes just somewhat difficult if I  am not allowed to post the actual code.   Any idea why I might get an error on `WriteAsync` at `await channel.Writer.WriteAsync(new T){...}, cancellationTokenSource.Token);` ?  Catching the exception on a try{} block just says a task was canceled

Comment: Even if you can't post your code, you *can* specify the library and post a relevant example that demonstrates the actual problem, like the QuickFix example. As for task cancellation, are you sure it's not an actual, legitimate cancellation? If the CancellationTokenSource is signalled all the methods that listen to it would throw. If you want to terminate gracefully, call `Complete` on the writer and let callers finish processing. `CancellationTokenSource` is needed when you want to stop everything immediately

Comment: Besides, whatever you're doing has already been done thousands of times over the last decade if not more. The libraries themselves contain documentation and examples that show how things are done. Nobody can claim copyright or trade secrets from common, publicly available code. You can adjust one of the public doc examples to demonstrate the actual issue

Comment: please check [github Link](https://github.com/derMaaster/FixAntennaExample_channel.git) if you have time

Comment: please see link to example above